# Possible for AVAssetWriter to write files with transparency?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avasset

Every file I write with AVAssetWriter has a black background, if the images I include do not fill the entire render area. Is there any way to write with transparency? Here's the method I use to get the pixel buffer:

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image {

    CGSize size = self.renderSize;

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, self.adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &pxbuffer);

    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          size.width,
                                          size.height,
                                          kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                          (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pxbuffer);


    if (status != kCVReturnSuccess){
        NSLog(@"Failed to create pixel buffer");
    }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                                 size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                                 (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

And the AVAssetWriter code:

```
NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.renderSize.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.renderSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];

AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                        assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings];

NSDictionary *bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
self.adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                    assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                    sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes];

buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[stickerImage CGImage]];

BOOL append_ok = YES;
    int j = 0;
    while (append_ok && j < totalFrames) {
        if (self.adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {

            CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) fps);
            append_ok = [self.adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
            if(!append_ok){
                NSError *error = self.assetWriter.error;
                if(error!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        }
        j++;
        frameCount++;
    }
    if (!append_ok) {
        printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: In 2020 this is now possible by using `AVVideoCodecTypeHEVCWithAlpha` but I haven't been able to get this to work... so if anyone can push us in the right direction that would be great :D

Answer (score 1):

In short, This is not possible. `AVAssetWriter` outputs using the h264 video codec. The h264 video codec does not support an alpha channel, so you are unfortunately out of luck.

A more involved solution would involve rendering the alpha channel (transparency) into a grayscale h264 encoded video and compositiong the rub and alpha information back together when viewing.

Comment: A working implementation of just such an approach built on top of OpenGL shaders can be found at this github link: https://github.com/mdejong/H264AlphaPlayer