# Video with transparent background created from AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor turns into black background

Tags: ios, screen-capture, avassetwriter, core-video, cvpixelbuffer

I am Creating video by capturing screen images with render context after every 0.01 second. The Captured images having the transparent background. But when creating video with these images using AVAssetWritter, AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor its transparent background is turned into black color.

I am using the Following code:-

canvasAssetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[self tempFileURL:@"output.mp4"] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];

```
NSParameterAssert(canvasAssetWriter);

//Configure video
NSDictionary* videoCompressionProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1024.0*1024.0], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                       nil ];

NSLog(@"System Version : %f WindowWidth : %f, windowHeight : %f",kSystemVersion,kWindowWidth,kWindowHeight);

NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:(kSystemVersion < 8.0)?kWindowHeight:kWindowWidth], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:(kSystemVersion < 8.0)?kWindowWidth:kWindowHeight], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                               nil];

canvasVideoAssetWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

NSParameterAssert(canvasVideoAssetWriterInput);
canvasVideoAssetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;


NSDictionary* bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCMPixelFormat_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

avAdaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:canvasVideoAssetWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes] retain];

//add input
[canvasAssetWriter addInput:canvasVideoAssetWriterInput];
[canvasAssetWriter startWriting];
[canvasAssetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];
```

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
                CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateCopy([capturedImage CGImage]);

```
            CFDataRef image = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage));


        pixelBuffer = [self pixelBufferFasterWithImage:cgImage];

            if(pixelBuffer !=nil)
            {
                // set image data into pixel buffer
                CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
                uint8_t* destPixels = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
                CFDataGetBytes(image, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(image)), destPixels);  //XXX:  will work if the pixel buffer is contiguous and has the same bytesPerRow as the input data

                BOOL success = [avAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time];
```

Comment: chack this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476605/how-to-encode-video-with-transparent-background

Comment: You cannot write a H264 video with an alpha channel, though it is possible to read one with a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12128695/763355